# Extend structs that conform to a protocol with a protocol

Tags: swift, swift2, protocols

I have a bunch of structs that define my value types. Many of them conform to a protocol I have called `DictConvertible`. I would like to make an extension that says that everything that implements `DictConvertible` will get this extension that implements `DataRepresentable` (from the [Haneke cache project](https://github.com/Haneke/Haneke)).

Is there a good way that I can express this? I thought I could do

```
extension DictConvertible : DataRepresentable { ... }
```

but I was mistaken

Update: I wasn't very clear, but the reason I wanted to make an extension is so that I can implement the functions defined in `DataRepresentable` so that I don't have to implement it in every struct that implements `DictConvertible`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Correct: you cannot extend a protocol to conform to ("inherit" from) another protocol. You should simply *define* the protocol to conform to the other protocol:

```
protocol DictConvertible : DataRepresentable {
     // ... and the rest as you already have it ...
}
```

Having done that, you can indeed then extend DictConvertible to provide default implementations of whatever DataRepresentable requires:

```
extension DictConvertible {
    func functionRequiredByDataRepresentable() {
        // ... code ...
    }
}
```

Alternatively, define a protocol that conforms to both of them:

```
protocol DictConvertibleAndDataRepresentable : DictConvertible, DataRepresentable {}
```

...and now you can make all and only those structs that do conform to both conform to this combining protocol. Again, you could then extend this protocol to provide default implementations of whatever DictConvertible or DataRepresentable requires.

Comment: Thanks. I realise now that I wasn't all that clear in my question, but in the extension (the { ... } bit) I wanted to implement the functions that implement the protocol ```DataRepresentable```. By making a protocol that inherits, I don't get to add this default implementation, right?

Comment: Wrong. :) As I said in my answer, your declaration that protocol A adopts protocol B cannot be in the extension to protocol A. But your _implementation_ of whatever protocol B declares certainly can be. Try it!

Comment: Added that to my answer.

Comment: Cool, thank you very much! :-) Now I understand much better, and was able to do as you suggested. :-) Thanks again! :-)

Comment: Glad to help. To be honest, I don't understand _why_ you can't use a protocol extension to declare the protocol's adoption of another protocol. This seems like an arbitrary hole in the language.